# C++ Array Inputing and Reversing Values

Tags: c++, arrays

For a project I need to write a program that reads in a series of positive integers, stored in an array, terminated by a -1. Then it should reverse the order of the array and print that along with the average of all the numbers.

ex: Input:  21 34 63
    Output: 63 34 21  Ave: 39.3

I am not sure where to begin. I thought maybe getting a user input in a while loop. So,

```
int num, i;
const int SIZE = 9;
int arr [SIZE] = {i};
i = 1;
while(num !=-1){
  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> num;
  arr[i] = num;
  i++;
}
cout << arr;
```

Okay so, first how do I create an array that takes user inputs and stores it as separate variables in the array? (Above is my unsuccessful attempt at that.)

Comment: i think you should think about what how are these inputs going to be stored. I'm guessing an array. Then, the next step would be how to reverse a given array.

Comment: `int arr [SIZE]` is going to be a problem if the user enters more than `SIZE` items.

Comment: And... What exactly is your question?

Comment: hint : reverse loop

Comment: hint++: reverse loop and summing all values then divide it by array.size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a simple problem. You first need to take the input and then reverse it.

```
     int num=0, i,j,k;
        const int SIZE = 99;     //any upperbound value, just to ensure user doesnt enter more values then size of array
        int arr [SIZE] = {0};    //better to initialize with 0
        i = 0;                    //considering 0 indexed
        int sum=0;                 // for average

        while(num !=-1){
          cout << "Enter a number: ";
          cin >> num;
          if(num!=-1)
          {
            arr[i] = num;
            sum+=num;
          } 
          i++;
        }

        int temp;

        //now reversing
        // size of the input array is now i
        for(j=0,k=i-1;j<k;j++,k--)
        {                                
           temp=arr[j];
           arr[j]=arr[k];
           arr[k]=temp;
        }

     //what i am doing here is- keeping the index j on the beginning of the
 //array and k to the end of the array. Then swap the values at j and k, then 
//increase j and decrease k to move to next pair of points. We do this until j is 
//less then k, means until we doesnt reach mid of the array


        //printing the reversed array and average

        cout<<"reversed array"<<endl;

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";

        cout<<"average"<<float(sum)/i;
```

**see the comments for suggestions**

Comment: If he just has to output the array and the reversed array, he doesn't necessarily need to reverse it in memory. Also, consider using std::swap instead of swapping the values using a temp.

Comment: ya i know that but the size of array isnt fixed.

Comment: It looks to be a good start, but the average it calculates is wrong because it is also adding 0 to it then dividing by the amount of numbers including 0. I think I can figure this out though. Thank you.

Comment: @RinionValvan that wasnt the problem. problem was that both sum and i were integers so it was converting the float result to integer(data loss). Fixed

Answer (score 1):

Since you are writing your program in c++, you should take a look at [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and the [reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) function that the [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)  provides you.
Using the above tools the solution to your problem is the following:

```
#include <vector>//include to use std::vector
#include <algorithm>//include to use reverse

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;                                                           
  int i;                                                                        
  float sum = 0.0f;                                                             
  while(std::cin>>i && i != -1)                                                 
  {                                                                             
    v.push_back(i);                                                             
    sum+=i;                                                                     
  }                                                                             
  reverse(v.begin(),v.end());                                                   
  for(int num : v)                                                              
    std::cout<<num<<" ";                                                        
  std::cout<<"average:"<<sum/v.size()<<std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: I think the user is new to c++ and must currently try simple ways.

Comment: @TanujYadav I just provided an alternative solution to the problem.Your solution is closer to the answer that the op is asking for but i will leave mine here since someone might find it useful.

Comment: ya sure, that would surely be useful for other users